# how to Select distinct from all columns - display the data to the first column where it occurs

Tags: mysql, select, mysql-workbench, distinct

I have a table named egsmaster
mysql workbench version : MySQL Workbench was 8.0.27

so i have this columns named number_id, product, french, german, english, italian
this language are the category for the product so i want to get a return list of distinct record from all the columns,

first get the distinct record from french, then german, english and italian so i did that

here is my query

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(category_french, '') AS french,
    COALESCE(category_german, '') AS german,
    COALESCE(category_english, '') AS english,
    COALESCE(category_italian, '') AS italian
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        category_french,
        category_german,
        category_english,
        category_italian
    FROM
        egsmaster
) AS t
WHERE
    COALESCE(category_french, '') <> ''
    OR COALESCE(category_german, '') <> ''
    OR COALESCE(category_english, '') <> ''
    OR COALESCE(category_italian, '') <> ''
    AND (category_french IS NOT NULL
    OR category_german IS NOT NULL
    OR category_english IS NOT NULL
    OR category_italian IS NOT NULL);
```

if i run this query i will get a result set like this

```
french | german | english | italian 
tree   |  tall  |  hall   |  itall
       |  aaa   |         |
       |        |  fff    |
       |        |         | yyyy
       | bds    | bgs     | itall
trek   | tall   |         |             
       |        |         | tr
trq    |  sss   |   ggg   | tret
12     |  re    |   a12   | ass
arrow  |  irrow |         |
back   |        |         | bock              
sap    |        |         | Sip
       | Itat   |  itaa   |
       |        |  Iasd   | kaka
       |        |         | sa,p
       |        |         | lasut
```

but what i want is to have a clean result set so that if i export it in excel it will show like this

```
french | german | english | italian |
tree     aaa      fff       yyyy
trek     bds      lasd      tr
trq      itat               sa,p
12                          lasut
arrow
back
sap
```

in a row if it has multiple columns that contains a data the first column where it occurs must be
the only that needs to return

regardless with the id what i only need to do is get the distinct data from all of the language column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea however, this only works on MySQL v8+.

I'll be using `Common Table Expression (cte)` and `ROW_NUMBER()` as main function and use `IFNULL()` as optional function - only if your data consists of both `NULL` and `''` for empty values.

First, we'll be using your example query as base and wrap that in the first `cte` like this:

```
/*1st part*/
WITH cat_tbl AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        category_french,
        category_german,
        category_english,
        category_italian
    FROM
        egsmaster
)
```

Now we use `cat_tbl` in our second `cte` to generate `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
/*1st part*/..,
/*2nd part*/
  cat_tblrn AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS Rn, cat_tbl.*
FROM cat_tbl)
```

Now we have the row number as reference for the next row number that we'll generate separately for each language column. According to your data sample, `category_french` is the first column to be list out. Here's a `cte` for it:

```
/*1st part*/..,
/*2nd part*/..,
/*3rd part - 1*/
cat_fr AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Rn) AS FrRn,
         category_french
  FROM cat_tblrn
  WHERE IFNULL(category_french,'')!=''),
```

`cat_fr` is the `cte` name with condition where `category_french` column value is not empty (or `NULL`).

Note: As I mentioned, if you're not sure empty data value is either `NULL` or `''`, then you can use `IFNULL()` function like in the query. However, if empty values are always `NULL` then you can change the part `IFNULL(column_name,'')!=''` to `column_name IS NOT NULL`. Or if empty column always `''` then simply `column_name != ''`.

The next `cte` is for `category_german`:

```
/*1st part*/..,
/*2nd part*/..,
/*3rd part - 2*/
cat_fr AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Rn) AS FrRn,
         category_french
  FROM cat_tblrn
  WHERE IFNULL(category_french,'')!=''),
cat_gr AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Rn) AS GrRn,
         category_german
  FROM cat_tblrn
  WHERE IFNULL(category_french,'')='' AND IFNULL(category_german,'')!='' )
```

The difference between this `cat_gr` and `cat_fr` cte are obviously the column in `SELECT` will be `category_german` with an additional `IFNULL(category_french,'')=''` in `WHERE` to indicate that `cat_gr` should only return value when `category_french` is empty. And the rest of the `cte` will have the same `WHERE` with additional checking of each previous column value that will end up something like this:

```
/*1st part*/..,
/*2nd part*/..,
/*3rd part - full*/
cat_fr AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Rn) AS FrRn,
         category_french
  FROM cat_tblrn
  WHERE IFNULL(category_french,'')!=''),
cat_gr AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Rn) AS GrRn,
         category_german
  FROM cat_tblrn
  WHERE IFNULL(category_french,'')='' AND IFNULL(category_german,'')!='' ),
cat_en AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Rn) AS EnRn,
         category_english
  FROM cat_tblrn
  WHERE IFNULL(category_french,'')='' AND IFNULL(category_german,'')='' 
    AND IFNULL(category_english,'')!=''),
cat_ita AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Rn) AS ItaRn,
         category_italian
  FROM cat_tblrn
  WHERE IFNULL(category_french,'')='' AND IFNULL(category_german,'')='' 
    AND IFNULL(category_english,'')='' AND IFNULL(category_italian,'')!='')
```

Now that we have all the `cte` prepared, we can simply use `LEFT JOIN` to get the desired result:

```
/*1st part*/..,
/*2nd part*/..,
/*3rd part*/..,
/*final part*/
SELECT category_french, 
       category_german,
       category_english,
       category_italian
  FROM cat_fr 
  LEFT JOIN cat_gr ON FrRn=GrRn
  LEFT JOIN cat_en ON FrRn=EnRn
  LEFT JOIN cat_ita ON FrRn=ItaRn;
```

Result:

| category_french | category_german | category_english | category_italian |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tree | aaa | fff | yyyy |
| trek | bds | Iasd | tr |
| trq | Itat |  | sa,p |
| 12 |  |  | lasut |
| arro |  |  |  |
| back |  |  |  |
| sap |  |  |  |

Get the full query in this [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3vKpPs8V)

Comment: yes yes, this what i want to achieve, i were just about to give up and use CASE statement to at least remove the other data in columns if it appear in the frnclmn, thank you i appreciate your help.

Comment: This is quite a customized query so, in my opinion it's only suitable to use in specific case but nonetheless, glad I could help and hopefully you'll find a more solid solution than this. Thanks for reposting the question too, I had write this answer when you posted the first one and when you deleted that, I kept this answer just in case you re-post the same question.

Comment: what if i want to add another column in the result set? do i need to add new CTE for that new column because the outer query cant access it inside cte

Comment: That depends on the column you want to add. If you're looking for the same result as the other 4 columns then, yes, you'll need a separate cte for it and update the final left join query accordingly. If the additional column is not intended to return the same type of result, that's a different thing.

Comment: You should take note as well that these other columns results are using `category_french` as reference for the `LEFT JOIN`. Therefore, if other columns return more rows than `category_french`, the result returned from that column will be limited to how many rows are there in `category_french`. You could modify the `LEFT JOIN` and use a pre-generated row numbering to prevent this issue.

Comment: Here's a fiddle to demonstrate what I mentioned in the last comment https://dbfiddle.uk/F4eBW_1B

Comment: Hi thank you for your feedback, and may i ask why does it still return record that is same, what are possible reason for that?

Comment: What do you mean the same record returned? Can you update the fiddle with the scenario you're asking? Or if this a follow up question on a different set of data or operation, it's better to post a new question to attract more attention.